# Django при добавлении записи в бд добавить еще несколько

Tags: python, django

Есть модель:

```
class Flight(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    from_place = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    to_place = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    airplane = models.ForeignKey(Airplane, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Полет номер {} из {} в {}'.format(self.id, self.from_place, self.to_place)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Полёт'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Полёты'
```

При добавлении элемента в нее нужно добавить еще несколько связанных элементов в другую модель:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    PLACE_CHOISES = (
        ('Средний класс', 'Средний класс'),
        ('Бизнес класс', 'Бизнес класс'),
        ('ВИП', 'ВИП'),
    )
    place_number = models.IntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    type = models.CharField(default='Средний класс', max_length=15, choices=PLACE_CHOISES)
    flight = models.ForeignKey(Flight, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Билет номер {} на место номер {}'.format(self.id, self.place_number)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Билет'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Билеты'
```

Идей как сделать это у меня нет, я попытался переписать метод Airplane.objects.create() но это не помогло (мб не правильно сделал что-то).

```
class FlightManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, date=None, from_place=None, to_place=None, airplane=None, price=None):
        flight = self.create(date, from_place, to_place, airplane, price)
        if airplane is not None:
            for i in range(1, airplane.places_amount - 6):
                ticket = Ticket.objects.create(place_number=i, flight=flight, price=price)
                ticket.objects.save()
            for i in range(airplane.places_amount - 5, airplane.places_amount - 2):
                ticket = Ticket.objects.create(place_number=i, flight=flight, type='Бизнес класс', price=price * 2)
                ticket.objects.save()
            for i in range(airplane.places_amount - 1, airplane.places_amount):
                ticket = Ticket.objects.create(place_number=i, flight=flight, type='ВИП', price=price * 5)
                ticket.objects.save()
        return flight
```

Comment: Просто [объявляете обработчик сигнала post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/) и в нём создаёте связанные записи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Flight)
def signal_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    for i in range(1, instance.airplane.places_amount):
        Ticket.objects.create(place_number=i, flight=instance, price=instance.price)
```

Answer (score 0):

Во вьюшке используешь следующее(вставь свои поля)

```
airplane = Airplane.objects.create(.....)
flight = Flight.objects.create(airplane=airplane, .....)
ticket = Ticket.objects.create(flight=flight, .....)
```

Не понятно зачем ты используешь manager

Comment: А если он создаёт записи ещё в админке, в management command и в таске Celery? Везде повторять этот код?

Comment: manager - один из первых запросов в гугле поэтому его и использовал (и как было сказано мной выше он не сработал), записи создаются только в админке поэтому я и задал вопрос. Где добавлять код для админки я не знаю, думаю что подход Сергея (post_signal) помог бы, но как его реализовать я не понял.

Comment: Используй post signal https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-save